# Car shakes when in gear when stopped but not while driving

Tags: automatic-transmission

So I have a 2007 jeep compass and motor runs great,  had and shakes in the motor/Trans area for a while.  I replaced the spark plugs, air filter and the motor and trans mounts and it helped a little bit. But I'm still getting the shake while stopped in gear ( more so in drive then reverse) wondering what would be the next thing that I would need to look into to get rid of the shake. Also my car has a constant velocity transmission and I did do a service on it when I bought the car a year ago.

Comment: What red light?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the mass air flow sensor?

Answer (score 1):

According to Rick's Free Auto Repair Advice - [Vibration at idle – Jeep](http://ricksfreeautorepairadvice.com/vibration-idle-jeep/), this is a known issue. Chrysler issued a technical service bulletin (18-017-08 Rev A) which requires a software upgrade to resolve the issue.

Check with the dealer service center to see if this has been completed on your Compass.